# About circular permutation

Tags: permutations

I know this is a physics group, but then I think you guys can answer me ..
anyone can explain how circular permutation work?
From the explanation from the book, it is understood that if CW $\ne$ ACW , it is $(n-1)!$.
if CW $=$ ACW, $(n-1)!/2$ . . . but then from the example that it give, it confuses me..help? test tomorrow >.<

Comment: What is CW ACW?

Comment: CW: clock-wise?  ACW: ????

Comment: That's what I thought at first... clockwise and.... anticlockwise?

Comment: What is $(n-1)!$ or $\frac {(n-1)!}2 ?$  By CW=ACW do you mean that reflections are considered identical?  Please state your question more clearly, instead of leaving us guessing.

Comment: This is not a Physics group!

Answer (score 4):

There are as you know $n!$ ways to arrange $n$ people in a row.

Now imagine arranging $n$ people around a circular table, where we count two seatings $A$ and $B$ as **the same** if everyone in seating $B$ has the same right-neghbour as in $A$, and the same left neighbour as in $A$. To count the number of such seatings, note that it doesn't matter where Alicia sits, all that matters is where the others are seated in *in relation* to Alicia. So seat Alicia in the best chair. The person to the right of Alicia can be chosen in $n-1$ ways. For each such way, the next person on the right can be chosen in $n-2$ ways. And for every $(n-1)(n-2)$ ways of selecting these two people, the next person to the right can be chosen in $(n-3)$ ways. And so on. The total number of ways is therefore $(n-1)\cdot(n-2)(n-3)\cdots(2)(1)$, or $(n-1)!$.  Note that this even works for $n=1$, since $0!$ is defined to be $1$.

Now imagine making a necklace with $n$ different circular beads. Consider two such necklaces $A$ and $B$ **the same** if $A$ can be *rotated* to look exactly like $B$, or $A$ can be rotated and *turned over* to look exactly like $B$. Turning over essentially reverses left and right. So (usually) if we allow turning over, the number of distinct necklaces gets divided by $2$. With rotation allowed, there were $(n-1)!$ of them, so with turning over allowed, the number is $(n-1)!/2$.

That is **not quite** fully correct. If $n=1$, turning the necklace over makes no difference, so the number of distinct permutations with turning over allowed is $1$.  Also, if $n=2$, every left neighbour is simultaneously a right neighbour. the number of circular permutations is $1$, and the number of permutations with turning over also allowed is again $1$. But for $n \ge 3$, the number of really different necklaces **is** $(n-1)!/2$.

Comment: Can you give some example where rotation is not allowed but reflection is ? What I mean is, is there some situation where the number of circular permutations is $(n-1)!$ ?

Comment: @user230452: The people around a table is $(n-1)!$, since whether $X$ is immediately to your left of immediately to your right may matter: People often have strong handedness preferences. For rotation matters but reflection does not, maybe think of a bracelet with a clasp and $n\ge 2$ different coloured beads. The number is then $n!/2$.